# JSF Richfaces Popuppanel bind to multiple fields

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a Richfaces popupPanel that we use to present a list of physicians to the user.

We have a requirement where the user can select a primary physician but can also select up to three other physicians as associated to the patient.

Each of the four fields invokes the popuppanel separately.

The problem is that I want to use one popuppanel to update up to four different fields depending on the user selecting more than one physician, but the command link action is bound to a method that updates only the primary physician field, I was wondering if it is possible to use the same popuppanel for all four fields by changing the action depending on which link was invoked to render the popuppanel.

I am also happy to try any other alternatives. Thanks

Comment: You can use the same popup for all cases. You need setup proper data in form bean on command link action and re-render popup (which will display form data).

Comment: Thanks, can you help with an example ?